# Vote rule-book as rules tag synonym 

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

Can you vote up about adding [rule-book](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rule-book) as synonym for [rules](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules)?

It has the same meaning and should be the same -

https://sports.stackexchange.com/tags/rules/synonyms